# Ubuntu 10.04 runs on VirtualBox and I want to connect to it through SSH

Tags: ubuntu, ssh, virtualbox

The host operating system is Windows 7, the guest operating system is ubuntu 10.04(openssh installed). I have internet access on Ubuntu but I also want to access it from the same computer throught SHH. What should I do?

Comment: migrate it to superuser !?

Comment: you might get better answer if you could ask it on http://askubuntu.com/

Answer (score 1):

This guide should help you [VirtualBox + Ubuntu + SSH + x11](http://geek.starbean.net/?p=167)

Answer (score 1):

You your virtual machine uses NAT networking you should forward SSH connection from your host to guest. You can do it by executing such command on host:

```
VBoxManage setextradata <guestname> "VBoxInternal/Devices/pcnet/0/LUN#0/Config/ssh/HostPort" 22222
VBoxManage setextradata <guestname> "VBoxInternal/Devices/pcnet/0/LUN#0/Config/ssh/GuestPort" 22
VBoxManage setextradata <guestname> "VBoxInternal/Devices/pcnet/0/LUN#0/Config/ssh/Protocol" TCP
```

It allows you to forward all connection to port 22222 on host machine to port 22 on guest machine.

Then you can execute SSH on your host:

```
ssh -p 22222 username@localhost
```

You have to connect to your localhost to port 22222 and these connection will be forwarded to the guest machine.

Answer (score 0):

Not quite a programming question, but anyways, to connect to your Linux host via SSH from Windows, you can use [PuTTY](http://www.chiark.greenend.org.uk/~sgtatham/putty/). Login to the virtual machine manually and run `ifconfig` command in the terminal to find out the IP address of the VM.

Comment: thanks for the answer, but unfortunately PuTTY just can't connect. On VirtualBox, the network adapter is attached to NAT if this is going to help somehow.

Comment: why don't u use a bridge to connect?

Answer (score 0):

In the virtualbox manager, create a 2nd virtual network card for the Ubuntu guest and set its type to host only (not NAT nor Bridged).
https://www.virtualbox.org/manual/ch06.html#network_hostonly